# Azure AD B2C custom policies : Delete TOTP information from User profile

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am referring this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003445#deleteclaims) to clears the information from a provided list of claims
.
I want to delete TOTP information from users profile using custom policies. But there is NO example/reference to clear these claims related to TOTP. I just want to know if its possible to delete TOTP information using custom policies from users profile or I need to use Graph API only.

Comment: Updating/Deleting totp registration not possible till date using custom policies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this is the best way to do it, but it will work.
Instead of 'removing claims', you can set them up to "" and then store it, the flows would be as following:
user wants to remove details:
1.- set claims to ""
2.- store claims and save them on B2C

When the user tries to log in again:

1.- Before MFA, read claims
2.- compare claims using claims transformation to ""
3.- if equal treat it as the user needs to introduce new details and save it (call the setotp subjourney)
4.- if not equal proceed